# Bizarre concurrent behavior when I cast `ConcurrentDictionary` to an `IDictionary`

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, thread-safety, concurrentdictionary

I have the following test:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;               

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(); // FAILS sometimes
        // ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(); // WORKS always

        Parallel.For(0, 10, i => dictionary.TryAdd("x1", "y1"));
    }
}
```

If I run it in .NET Fiddle, I sometimes get the following exception:

> Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The key already existed in the dictionary)
> System.ArgumentException: The key already existed in the dictionary.
>
> at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey,TValue>.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
> at System.Collections.Generic.CollectionExtensions.TryAdd[TKey,TValue](IDictionary`2 dictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
> at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(Int32 i)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`2.b__1(RangeWorker& currentWorker, Int64 timeout, Boolean& replicationDelegateYieldedBeforeCompletion)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`2.b__1(RangeWorker& currentWorker, Int64 timeout, Boolean& replicationDelegateYieldedBeforeCompletion)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskReplicator.Replica.Execute()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

However, if I don't cast `ConcurrentDictionary`, it seems to always work.

What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually covered in the [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-8.0#thread-safety) docs in the "Thread Safety" section which is hidden that far away so almost everybody misses it (emphasis mine):

> ##### Thread Safety
>
> All public and protected members of `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads. **However, members accessed through one of the interfaces the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` implements, including extension methods, are not guaranteed to be thread safe and may need to be synchronized by the caller.**

And the `IDictionary<string, string> dictionary = ..` falls under the extensions methods category, specifically [`CollectionExtensions.TryAdd<TKey,TValue>(IDictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary, ...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.tryadd?view=net-8.0#system-collections-generic-collectionextensions-tryadd-2(system-collections-generic-idictionary((-0-1))-0-1))

So in short - if you need to use the dictionary in thread-safe manner do not use it via interfaces/extension methods and use the methods listed in the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-8.0#remarks) section:

> All these operations are atomic and are thread-safe with regards to all other operations on the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` class...

Answer (score 8):

The [ConcurrentDictionary.TryAdd instance method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryadd) operates in an atomic manner. If this method is called twice simultaneously with the same key, then one of the calls is guaranteed to return `false` (instead of throwing an exception).

The generic IDictionary interface has no TryAdd instance method. When you cast to IDictionary and call TryAdd, you're actually invoking the [CollectionExtensions.TryAdd extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.tryadd). This method is [implemented](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/CollectionExtensions.cs,fc8ad34b5b2199c1) as follows:

```
if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
{
    dictionary.Add(key, value);
    return true;
}
 
return false;
```

As you can see, this implementation is *not* atomic. Two simultaneous calls to TryAdd can both pass the ContainsKey check and then both call [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.system-collections-generic-idictionary-tkey-tvalue--add), which results in an exception.

Therefore, you can't cast to IDictionary and preserve the atomic behavior of the ConcurrentDictionary.TryAdd instance method.